# How to get the relative rotation of 2 quaternions in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions, imu

I'm trying to obtain the angle between the upperarm en lowerarm using two IMU's respectively. I calibrate both imu's and use Quaternions to get global orientation of the upperarm and lowerarm object in Unity 3D.

Qimu1 = Quaternion from the imu located on the lowerarm

Qimu2 = Quaternion from the imu located on upperarm.

I made two objects in Unity representing the upperarm en lowerarm. Where the lowerarm is a child object of the upperarm and is connected to the upperarm using Character joint.

This is the script for the upperarm:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Qstart2 = Qimu2;
        }

        transform.localRotation = Qstart2 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu2);
```

Lowerarm script:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Qstart1 = Qimu1;
        }

        Qimu1new = Qstart1 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu1);
        Quaternion Qdiff = Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu1new) * Qimu2;
        transform.localRotation = Qdiff;
```

What i would like to acquire is a visual representation of arm movement in Unity3D using 2 IMU's. Now if i keep my elbow extended the script works. But as soon as i start to flex my elbow the lowerarm object starts to continuously rotate around the same axis.

Comment: Can you explain more about `Qstart1` and `Qstart2`? Are they being changed or set somewhere else?

Comment: Qstart is initially empty, it is a way to calibrate the IMU. As it starts to calculate its relative orientation from the time i press space. Therefore it is set once.

Comment: Try `transform.localRotation =  Quaternion.Inverse(Qstart2 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu2)) * Qimu1new;`

Comment: did that do what you expected?

Comment: Yes! It actually did! Sorry i couldnt test it before. But this is exactly what i needed. Thanks! Dont really understand why though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use some algebra to find the calculation for the lower arm transform's relative rotation:

The formula `Qstartx * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimux)` gives you a rotation for that part relative to the body:

```
upper arm's rotation relative to body = Qstart2 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu2)
lower arm's rotation relative to body = Qstart1 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu1)
```

We know that since lower arm is a child of the upper arm:

```
lower arm's rotation relative to body 
    = upper arm's rotation relative to body * lowerArmTransform.relativeRotation
```

With substitution, we can determine:

```
Qstart1 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu1) 
    = (Qstart2 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu2)) * lowerArmTransform.relativeRotation
```

Multiply both sides on the left by `Quaternion.Inverse(Qstart2 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu2))`:

```
Quaternion.Inverse(Qstart2 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu2)) * Qstart1 
* Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu1) 
    = Quaternion.Inverse(Qstart2 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu2)) 
      * ( Qstart2 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu2) )
      * lowerArmTransform.relativeRotation
```

`Quaternion.Inverse(Qstart2 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu2)) * ( Qstart2 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu2) )` cancel out:

```
Quaternion.Inverse(Qstart2 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu2)) * Qstart1 
* Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu1) 
    = lowerArmTransform.relativeRotation
```

Since `Qimu1new = Qstart1 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu1);`, we can conclude:

#### `lowerArmTransform.relativeRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(Qstart2 * Quaternion.Inverse(Qimu2)) * Qimu1new;`